# click event on ngbDropdownItem is not working in iPhone with Zoom in

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

I have a angular 8 web app where I use ngbDropdown. I have attached click event to ngbDropdownItem. It works. But when I zoon in the web app in iPhone, click event is not working.

```
<div ngbDropdown container="body" class="d-inline-block">
                        <button class="btn btn-outline-primary" ngbDropdownToggle>Toggle dropdown</button>
                        <div ngbDropdownMenu>
                            <button ngbDropdownItem (click)="test()">Action - 1</button>
                            <button ngbDropdownItem (click)="test()">Another Action</button>
                            <button ngbDropdownItem (click)="test()">Something else is here</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi use focus event instead of click.

```
<div ngbDropdown container="body" class="d-inline-block">
                        <button class="btn btn-outline-primary" ngbDropdownToggle>Toggle dropdown</button>
                        <div ngbDropdownMenu>
                            <button ngbDropdownItem (focus)="test()">Action - 1</button>
                            <button ngbDropdownItem (focus)="test()">Another Action</button>
                            <button ngbDropdownItem (focus)="test()">Something else is here</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```